# Copying row specific conditional formatting formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, conditional-formatting

I have a lot of data in Excel (2007 if that makes a difference) and I need to conditionally format it so that my overall value in `W5` to `W115` will change colour if it is not equal to the sum of `X5` to `AE5`, `6`, `7`, etc so each row needs a different **formula** in the formatting box.

I've attached a picture of what I'm working on. I've tried following lots of different tutorials online doing things like removing the `$` sign around the cell numbers and using different formatting rules but just can't figure it out.

Can anyone help at all?

[image]

Comment: Is the format of your report locked, or could you add a helper column (say AF) that sums `X` through `AE`?

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't appear to be a question about programming but rather about general use of Excel and as such is off-topic on this site. You might find help at [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: @pnuts This question is NOT about Excel formulas, it's about Conditional Formatting. Neither does the asker actually state or demonstrate that he has tried or is searching for a VBA solution, leading me to believe the question was tagged incorrectly. At the time I made my original comment, this question had no answers. The [conditional-formatting] tag description even states you should consider asking your question on SuperUser if it is not specifically about accessing Conditional Formatting from VBA/VSTO/Similar.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to solve this issue without the use of a helper column, you could use a small script like the following:

```
Option Explicit
Sub HighlightDiscrepancies()

Dim LastRow As Long, Counter As Long
Dim RowSum As Double, MatchAgainst As Double
Dim MySheet As Worksheet

'set references up-front
Set MySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<~ assume data on Sheet1
With MySheet
    LastRow = .Cells.Find("*", _
                         SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                         SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
End With

'loop through each row, comparing the sum of X through AE to
'the value in W
With MySheet
    For Counter = 1 To LastRow
        'set the value in col W to the match variable below
        MatchAgainst = .Cells(Counter, 23).Value
        'set the sum of col X to col AE in the sum variable below
        RowSum = Application.Sum(.Range(.Cells(Counter, 24), .Cells(Counter, 31)))
        'use an if statement to compare values, making the cell red
        'if the sum variable is not equal to the match variable
        If MatchAgainst <> RowSum Then
            .Cells(Counter, 23).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If
    Next Counter
End With

End Sub
```

To summarize, we:

- Define variables up-front, setting the `Worksheet` and `LastRow`
- Loop through all rows using `For...Next`

  - Assign the value in column W to `MatchAgainst`
  - Assign the sum of values in columns X through AE to `RowSum`
  - Compare `MatchAgainst` to `RowSum`, highlighting the cell if they are not equal